Initial value of Observable is not used
I tried to make a HttpWrapper service to wrap the return object with a wrapper with loading value to load a spinner. At first, I initialize the Observable with loading: true but it didn't work. The observable looks like null or undefined until get updated when API call is completed.
The wrapper service:
import { inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, delay, map, Observable, of, switchMap } from 'rxjs';

export interface ApiResponse<T> {
  data: T | null;
  loading: boolean;
  error?: Error | null;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class HttpWrapperService {
  #httpClient = inject(HttpClient);

  get<T>(url: string, params?: HttpParams): Observable<ApiResponse<T>> {
    return of({ data: null, loading: true, error: null }).pipe(
      delay(5000),
      switchMap(() =>
        this.#httpClient.get<T>(url, { params, withCredentials: true }).pipe(
          map(
            (data) => ({ data, loading: false, error: null } as ApiResponse<T>)
          ),
          catchError((error) =>
            of({ data: null, loading: false, error } as ApiResponse<T>)
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}


The template:
<span>Loading: {{(dataObservable | async)?.loading}}</span>

#httpWrapper = inject(HttpWrapperService);

  dataObservable: Observable<ApiResponse<any>> = of({
    data: null,
    loading: true,
    error: null,
  });

  constructor() {
    this.dataObservable = this.#httpWrapper.get(
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
    );
  }

I tried to init the dataObservable with an Observable but it didn't work either. The loading value is undefined and change to false when the call is finished.
Here is a simple repo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-4jyxfj5l?file=src%2Fmain.ts

You're close. You need to use startsWith like below:
get<T>(url: string, params?: HttpParams): Observable<ApiResponse<T>> {
  const initialVal = { data: null, loading: true, error: null };

  return of(initialVal).pipe(
    delay(5000),
    switchMap(() => this.#httpClient.get<T>(url, { params, withCredentials: true }).pipe(
      map(data => ({ data, loading: false, error: null } as ApiResponse<T>)),
      catchError((error) => of({ data: null, loading: false, error } as ApiResponse<T>))
    )),
    startWith(initialVal)
  );
}


Not sure why I put startWith first, without of and switchMap, the code didn't work and I can't figure out why

of is observable, and startWith is an operator that you can pipe into the stream. All you needed was a stream to pipe into. @RaphaëlVO

Instead of switchMapping from an initial value, use startWith:

Returns an observable that, at the moment of subscription, will synchronously emit all values provided to this operator, then subscribe to the source and mirror all of its emissions to subscribers.

import { catchError, map, startWith } from 'rxjs';

return this.#httpClient.get<T>(url, { params, withCredentials: true }).pipe(
  map(
    (data) => ({ data, loading: false, error: null } as ApiResponse<T>)
  ),
  catchError((error) =>
    of({ data: null, loading: false, error } as ApiResponse<T>)
  ),
  startWith({ data: null, loading: true, error: null } as ApiResponse<T>),
);


I did use it at first but it didn't work, so I tried to use of and switchMap, now when I copied your code, it works, sounds so strange
